# Plots.jl legend text color?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Simple but seemingly non-answered question:

Is it possible to customize the legend in Plots.jl so as to have the different
text labels in different text colors? With the GR backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work with legendfontcolor, if you use one plot! statement per color:

```
julia> using Plots

julia> plot(rand(10), linecolor = :red, legendfontcolor=:red)

julia> plot!(rand(10), linecolor = :blue, legendfontcolor=:blue)
```